# How to monitor website changes like google analytics in android mobile application

Tags: android, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to create an android mobile application which will constantly monitor a particular website changes which has google analytics and want to show the webpage traffic like pageviews, number of visitors,search traffic, real time active users for the website. These resulting graph should be showed in android mobile application. Any idea how to create an application? Which API will help to get the analytics data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) will give you all the data within your analytics account. In fact the [Google Analytics Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant) uses the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mix Panel service.its very light weight and more useful for your application

Site URL : https://mixpanel.com/